# Fraction Simplification in Sequence Definitions

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, fractions

There is a test problem which asks you to define a non-recursive formula for this sequence:
$$\{\frac21, \frac44, \frac69, \frac8{16}, \frac{10}{25}, \ldots \}$$

I saw the relationship $a_n = \frac{2n}{n^2}$, which I simplified to $\frac2n$ and marked that as my final answer.
This was marked wrong as while $\frac2n$ gave the exact same values, it produced a sequence that is $\{\frac21, \frac22, \frac23, \frac24, \frac25, \ldots\}$ instead of the above sequence. Even though the numbers are the same, my teacher argues that the simplification makes the sequences different.

She asks for a mathematical proof or a logical statement that these two sequences are the same. She says she is open to reconsidering if she reads a logical and mathematical argument by a mathematician.

Is $\frac2n$ right? If it is, can you provide a mathematical proof for that?

Comment: You have provided a nice argument here yourself. Did you write that on your test, or was "The sequence is $a_n=\frac 2n$" your entire answer? Because I would've marked that as wrong myself, or at least n nowhere near full marks.

Comment: In short, the sequences are equal $\{\frac21,\frac44,\frac69,\frac8{16},\frac{10}{25},\ldots\}=\{2,1,\frac23,\frac12,\frac25,\ldots\}=\{\frac21,\frac22,\frac23,\frac24,\frac25,\ldots\}$ because they are termwise equal

Comment: *makes the sequences different* .. In what way? Does she argue that $\frac{6}{9} \neq \frac{2}{3}$ and so on?

Comment: @sirfoga To be fair, it does become a different sequence of fractions. The numbers are the same, but the fractions are different. I'm not saying that that's a good or a correct way of looking at it, and a teacher ought to know better, but I can understand where the idea comes from. (Also, we haven't heard the teacher's side of this story, or seen the exact answer as given on the test.)

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$
You have proven it.

$$\frac{2n}{n^2}=\frac{2\cdot {n}}{n \cdot {n}}=\frac{2\cdot \cancel{n}}{n \cdot \cancel{n}}=\frac{2}{n}.$$

The cancelation is valid since $n>0$.

The sequences  $$\{\frac21,\frac44,\frac69,\frac8{16},\frac{10}{25},\ldots\}=\{2,1,\frac23,\frac12,\frac25,\ldots \}=\{\frac21,\frac22,\frac23,\frac24,\frac25,\ldots\}$$

because they are termwise equal.

Credit: Hagen vonEitzen's comment.

Comment: Try including Hagen von Eitzen's comment to complete your answer.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the suggestion.